# Dependency injection fails with @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.3.RELEASE to build a new MVC application.

I have a Customer entity as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled;
}
```

I have a CustomerRepository as follows:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Integer> {

}
```

I have a CustomerService as follows:

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    CustomerMapper customerMapper;

    public CustomerDto save(CustomerDto customerDto) {

        Customer customer = customerMapper.map(customerDto, Customer.class);

        customerRepository.save(customer);

        return customerMapper.map(customer, CustomerDto.class);
    }

    public CustomerDto findById(int id) {

        Customer customer = customerRepository.findOne(id);

        return customerMapper.map(customer, CustomerDto.class);
    }
}
```

My application is defined as:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CoreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CoreApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My JPA configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class PersistenceConfig {

}
```

I have written a test as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;

    @Test
    public void testCustomerService() {

        CustomerDto customerDtoIn = new CustomerDto();

        customerDtoIn.setName("Test Customer");
        customerDtoIn.setEnabled(true);

        customerService.save(customerDtoIn);

        CustomerDto customerDtoOut = customerService.findById(customerDtoIn.getId());

        assertThat(customerDtoOut).isEqualTo(customerDtoIn);
    }
}
```

The structure I have followed is:

```
com.app.core <- CoreApplication lives here
com.app.core.repositories <- Repositories here
com.app.core.services <- Services here
```

However, when I try to run this test case I get the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException
No qualifying bean of type 'com.app.core.repositories.CustomerRepository' available
```

Can someone tell me why the dependency injection is failing? From reading the spring-boot docs `@SpringBootTest` and `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` are all I need to test my service layer.

Comment: how does your main class look like? and what is the directory structure you have followed? Are you able to run your application

Comment: I have updated the question with some more detail. I haven't created the controller layer yet so don't have an application to run. I can build the application fine if I skip the tests.

Comment: you don't need any controller to run your application. just try starting your application and see if it stars without any exception

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I've tried running the app and it fails with the same exception. This must mean the issue is with the base configuration but I can't work out where the issue is.

Comment: okay. so that means it is not the prolem with your Tests. Its a problem with your application itself. It is not scanning your Repository. How does your `PersistenceConfig` look like?

Comment: I don't know whether something has changed in spring-boot since I last used it but I had to change `@EnableJpaRepositories` to `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.app.core.repositories")`. Thanks for your help @pvpkiran

Comment: You should remove your `PersistenceConfig` (if it is as you show here) as Spring Boot already does all of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add base package and repository base package into `ApplicationContext.xml`. yo can use below code:-

```
<context:component-scan annotation-config="true"
    base-package="com.demo.test" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.demo.test.repository" />
```

Comment: I have updated my question with some more detail. I'm not using xml-based config and I believe the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is all I need.